# How to test if container is running postgres

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I just deployed a docker with Postgres on it on AWS EKS.

Below is the description[image] details.

How do i access or test if postgres is working. I tried accessing both IP with post within VPC from worker node.

```
 psql -h #IP -U #defaultuser -p 55432
```

Below is the deployment.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  containers:
    - name: postgres
      image: postgres:10.4
      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 55432
      # envFrom:
      #   - configMapRef:
      #       name: postgres-config
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: postgredb
  volumes:
    - name: postgredb
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: efs
```

Surprisingly I am able to connect to psql but on 5432. :( Not sure what I am doing wrong. I passed containerPort as 55432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you need to run the following command to expose your database on 55432 port.

```
kubectl expose deployment postgres --port=55432 --target-port=5432 --name internal-postgresql-svc
```

From now on, you can connect to it via port 55432 from inside your cluster by using the service name as a hostname, or via its ClusterIP address:

```
kubectl get internal-postgresql-svc
```

What you did in your deployment manifest file, you just attached additional information about the network connections a container uses, between misleadingly, because your container exposes 5432 port only (you can verify it by your self [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/cc305ee1c59d93ac1808108edda6556b879374a4/10/Dockerfile#L174)). 
You should use a Kubernetes [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) - abstraction which enables access to your PODs, and does the necessary port mapping behind the scene. 
Please check also [different](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) port Types, if you want to expose your postgresql database outside of the Kubernetes cluster.

---

To test if progress is running fine inside POD`s container:

```
kubectl run postgresql-postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --namespace default --image bitnami/postgresql --env="PGPASSWORD=<HERE_YOUR_PASSWORD>" --command -- psql --host <HERE_HOSTNAME=SVC_OR_IP> -U <HERE_USERNAME>
```

Comment: Ty nepomucen could you take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/55013866/8453102