# k8s - IP and DNS for postgres with service

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have created stateful service which is backed by a postgres deployment with k8s.

Setup is 3 public subnet|AZ and 3 private subnet|AZ. postgres deployment is in place to create 1 replica and Service with `clusterIP: none`

But now every time I delete the service and create again IP is changing and I was reading something about DNS resolution. I want to access the DB from java client to be deployed another pod on n/w; here i am unable to get static IP.

Can I create a service with `clusterIP: #some_IP_from_one_of_the_subnet_range#`? What will happen if the service goes down and k8s respawns it? Will it be started in same AZ and subnet? what if AZ is down?

Comment: Whenever your service has changed the relevant endpoint IP address, it can always be possible to access the service by DNS service A record, you might be interested in details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services).

Comment: Hi mk_sta. Thank you for the link. I can access the service by dns name but when pods are restarted dns would resolve to new ip right?

Comment: I’m concerned about dns resolution and dns ttl. Some client like java clients don’t respect dns ttl.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced the issue you have reported. I have created a postgres cluster and also created a K8S service for the cluster.

The cluster looks like

```
root@k8-master:~# kubectl get pods
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kibana                      1/1     Running   0          9s
postgres-59bcb7c9d4-lvg8v   1/1     Running   0          56m
postgres-59bcb7c9d4-rfppm   1/1     Running   0          56m
postgres-59bcb7c9d4-s9zc4   1/1     Running   0          56m
```

After creating the cluster and service

The service provides a service name which also translates to a IP address with the help of k8s DNS resolution.

So we need not use a static IP address for the postgres cluster, because the postgres k8s service will help you connect to the cluster containers.
To prove that I have sent a curl request by using the service name rather than the IP address.

```
root@k8-master:~# kubectl exec -it kibana /bin/bash
bash-4.2$ curl http://postgres:5432
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
bash-4.2$ exit
```

When you create the cluster for the postgres, please make sure that the endpoints are connected to one of your cluster containers. It should look like this,

```
root@k8-master:~# kubectl describe services postgres
Name:                     postgres
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=postgres
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"postgres"},"name":"postgres","namespace":"default"},"spe...
Selector:                 app=postgres
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.97.201.134
Port:                     <unset>  5432/TCP
TargetPort:               5432/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30362/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.1.12:5432,10.244.1.13:5432,10.244.2.242:5432
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

In the above example the endpoints are assigned to 10.244.1.12 and others. If that field is empty then the access to the postgres service will yield no result.

Another way of saying this is, the service merely redirects the request to the cluster. If the cluster doesn't recognize the service then the access from Java won't work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi keerthi how did you spin up the Postgres cluster? In my case I have single pod for Postgres.

Comment: Hi Pat, we have replicated the postgres container to be more than 1. I think what you are asking about is postgres cluster service. You can find examples to create services in k8s docs. Please let me know if you need specific information.